# Not able to convert a string value to Date time including milliseconds

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string value which I need to convert to DateTime

**currentDate="29-APR-17 03.42.06.410000 PM"**

I tried the below statement, but its throwing error:

```
DateTime originalDate = DateTime.Parse(currentDate);
DateTime originalDate = Convert.ToDateTime(currentDate);
```

I even followed this link "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882581(v=vs.110).aspx"
but is is also not helping

Moreover, the information provided in Stackoverflow was not helping as I am always facing the error **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact is your way out here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx) should solve the formatting like this:

```
DateTime originalDate = DateTime.ParseExact(currentDate, "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.ffffff tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

or if time part are separated with colons:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(currentDateWithColons, "dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss.ffffff tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Both dots and colons producing the same result using `Console.WriteLine(originalDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.ffffff tt"))`:

```
29/04/2017 03:42:06.410000 PM
```

Working example: [.NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nMbaLW)

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
string currentDate="29-APR-17 03:42:06.410000 PM"
DateTime originalDate = DateTime.Parse(currentDate);
originalDate = Convert.ToDateTime(currentDate);
Console.WriteLine(originalDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-fff"));
```

you were using wrong format use : instead of . in time.

changed "29-APR-17 ***03.42.06***.410000 PM" to "29-APR-17 ***03:42:06***.410000 PM"

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. It still does not shows millisecond value. Which is my requirement.

Comment: @Yash Console.WriteLine(originalDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-fff"));

Comment: use ToString() method and custom datetime format if you want to show millisecond value. working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

```
string currentDate = "29-APR-17 03:42:06.410000 PM";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(currentDate, "dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss.ffffff tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[image]